# Hit a URL on other server from google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url

I want to hit a URL from python in google app engine. Can any one please tell me how can i hit the URL using python in google app engine.

Comment: Poor URL! Seriously though, what do you mean by "hit"?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [URLFetch API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html)

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

url = "http://www.google.com/"
result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
if result.status_code == 200:
  doSomethingWithResult(result.content)
```

Comment: I want to fetch this URL via GAE cron job. But I am getting failure.Can you please tell me How can I fetch this URL via cron job? As I cannot test this this from my local machine.

Comment: We need more details than just "failure".

Answer (score 0):

It always depends on post or get. urllib can post to a form somewhere else, if we want the rather tricky thing validate between different hashes (sha and md5)

```
import urllib             
data = urllib.urlencode({"id" : str(d), "password" : self.request.POST['passwd'], "edit" : "edit"})
result = urlfetch.fetch(url="http://www..../Login.do",
payload=data,
method=urlfetch.POST,
headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
if result.content.find('loggedInOrYourInfo') > 0:                    
  self.response.out.write("clear")                          
else:                
  self.response.out.write("wrong password ")
```